# Calculate the limit in distribution of the sequence $(n (1 - M_{n} + m_{n})) \ n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is the limit a distribution known?

Tags: probability

I think the platform only accepts one exercise per question.
I have this last question, how can I get the cumulative distribution function of the sequence given below with the given hypotheses?

Let $(U_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables i.i.d. with uniform distribution in the interval $[0, 1]$.
We define for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the random variables:
$$M_{n} = \max\{U_{1} ,...,U_{n}\}$$
$$m_{n} = \min\{U_{1} ,...,U_{n}\}$$

Calculate the limit in distribution of the sequence $(n (1 - M_{n} + m_{n})) \ n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is the limit a distribution known?

Now I have to:

$$F_{m_{n}}(a)=1-(1-a)^n$$

$$F_{M_{n}}(a)=a^{n}$$
With $$m_n\xrightarrow{d}0$$

$$M_n\xrightarrow{d}1$$

$$m_n-M_n\xrightarrow{d}-1$$

Always appreciating your help.

Comment: An easy observation is that $n (1 - M_{n} + m_{n})$ is non-negative. Another is that  $\mathbb E[n (1 - M_{n} + m_{n})] = 2-\frac{2}{n+1}$ which increases towards $2$ as $n$ increases, so if there is a limiting distribution, its mean must be $2$.